# Error: Parameter out was not defined for stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

When I call this stored procedure:

```
procedure [dbo].[pTest]
     @Date varchar(max) =null
as
begin
select * from test
end
```

from java using Spring Data JPA 1.10.2 with com.microsoft.sqlserver's sqljdbc 4.2. I get no error. But when I add another parameter to the procedure

```
procedure [dbo].[pTest]
     @ReportData varbinary(max) out
     ,@Date varchar(max) =null
as
begin
select * from test
end
```

I get the following error:

```
2016-10-06 15:50:16.283 DEBUG 32604 --- [           main] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : *** SQLException:SQLServerCallableStatement:9 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter out was not defined for stored procedure pTest. Parameter out was not defined for stored procedure pTest.
2016-10-06 15:50:16.289 DEBUG 32604 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error preparing CallableStatement [pTest]

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter out was not defined for stored procedure pTest.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191) ~[sqljdbc-4.2.jar:na]
```

If I remove the `@Date` parameter and modify the code accordingly, I get no error. Once I add back the `@Date` parameter to have two parameters, I get the error again. Why?

The code for two params is as follows:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Test.getTest", procedureName = "pTest", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "Date", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "ReportData", type = byte[].class)
          })
public class Test {

    // serves no purpose other than to meet
    // JPA requirement
    @Id
    private byte[] reportData;
}
```

Spring data repository:

```
public interface TestRepository  extends Repository<Test, Long> {
    @Procedure("pTest")
    byte[] get(@Param("Date") String date);
}
```

Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional(transactionManager="transactionManager")
public class TestRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws SQLException {

        byte[] blob = testRepository.get("hi");
        //error occurs
    }

}
```

Comment: If I use jTDS, I get the error `Procedure or function 'pTest' expects parameter '@ReportData', which was not supplied.` I'm using SQL Server 2005 but it also seems to have the same behavior with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Order of parameters could be import, have you tried witching the order of your parameters so you declare the `OUT` first in the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` definition, or the `OUT` second in your stored procedure DDL?

Comment: I changed the order such that `OUT` was first in the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`. I still receive the same error though. I did figure out a solution to the issue. I'll post it, but it would be great to understand why the code in OP doesn't work.

Comment: Found the correct solution... I think:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue :) The attribute name of `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` needs to match the repository method name. So change this:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Test.getTest", procedureName = "pTest", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "Date", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "ReportData", type = byte[].class)
          })
```

to this:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Test.get", procedureName = "pTest", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "Date", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "ReportData", type = byte[].class)
          })
```